# I wanted to delete one item, but instead its deleting the whole database

Tags: javascript, mongoose, vue.js, mongoose-schema

This is how I display it

```
    <tr v-for="(foodItem, index) in filteredFoodItems">
       <td>{{ foodItem.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ foodItem.price | currency('£') }}</td>
       <td>{{ foodItem.category }}</td>
       <td><a @click="removeItem(index)" class="button is-danger is-outlined">
           <span>Delete</span>
           <span class="icon is-small">
              <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
           </span>
         </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

This is what I use to delete

```
router.delete('/', function (req, res) {
  let itemToRemove = req.body;
  let FoodItem = mongoose.model('FoodItem', FoodItemSchema);
  FoodItem
    .find(itemToRemove)
    .remove(itemToRemove, err => {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
    })
})
```

When I clicked the button it deleted the whole database data instead of the selected item in the database. In the v-for I put index so that each food item has an index and then on the @click I put removeItem(index) so it refers to that one but it has deleted the whole database? Can anyone spot what I have done wrong? thanks in advance!

Here is the removeItem

```
removeItem(itemToRemove) {
            axios.delete('/api/menu', this.foodItems[itemToRemove])
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                });
        }
    },
```

Comment: So you think `removeItem` is not important to post here?

Comment: `removeItem` is basically index

Comment: @Andrew - I think dfsq means we need to see the `removeItem()` function in oder to understand how to help you.

Comment: Sorry guys its here

Comment: `removeItem(itemToRemove) {
            axios.delete('/api/menu', this.foodItems[itemToRemove])
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                });
        }
    },`

Comment: Why are you operating on two different arrays? In your `v-for` you use **`filteredFoodItems`** while in the `removeItem()` function you use the **`foodItems`** array.

Comment: I use two because one is all the `fooditems` and the one I want to display is the filtered version, but this could be the reason not sure, Its just deleting everything, I'm not too experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your router code you rely upon the response body to determine what to delete. Yet in your axios code you don't load the response body, you only supply an array element.  So...

**Change**

```
axios.delete('/api/menu', this.foodItems[itemToRemove])
```

**To**

```
axios.delete('/api/menu', {data:this.foodItems[itemToRemove]})
```

that simple change should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine. Though, you need to use `:key` binding so that `index` would be respected while rendering the list:

```
<tr v-for="(foodItem, index) in filteredFoodItems" :key="index">
```

Also, you have link tag and using click handler on it should be prevented it's default:

```
@click.prevent="removeItem(index)"
```